# Link to download the submitted Powerform

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

How to get the link to download the submitted powerform. The PDF file will be sent to the email and it is downloadable from the docuSign admin also. But I need to provide a link to download the submitted file for an admin user on my website. is it possible?

Comment: Hi Adam,
DocuSign does not presently supply static links to download completed PDFs.

In order to download the PDF without accessing DocuSign's website directly, you'll need to be able to authorize as an admin on the account that sent the envelope, or someone that interacted with the envelope. Once authenticated, you can use an API call to retrieve the PDF directly from DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, but you will have to build a web app.
The web app you built will have and endpoint that takes an envelopeID and returns back a PDF. It will call the DocuSign eSignature REST API every time someone is requesting to download an envelope and will provide it.
You can use JWT to authenticate your web app impersonating the administrator of this account so you always have access to download any envelope.
Note that if you build something like this, you're exposing the envelopes in your account to anyone that knows the URLs , so it's not recommended to do so unless you know your account is only used for non-sensitive documents.